# Why is inherited member not allowed?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm beginner to C++ and I'm doing one of the exercises about abstract class and inheritance.

This is my abstract class:

```
#ifndef   SHAPE_H 
#define  SHAPE_H
class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual void area();
        virtual void perimeter();
        virtual void volume();
};
#endif
```

This is my concrete class that implements the abstract class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

class Circle : public Shape
{
    public:
        Circle(int);
    private:
        int r;
};

Circle::Circle(int rad)
{
    r = rad;
}

void Circle::area()
{
    cout << "Area of this cirle = " << 3.14 * pow(r, 2) << endl;
}

void Circle::perimeter()
{
    cout << "Perimeter of this cirle = " << 2 * 3.14 * r << endl;
}

void Circle::volume()
{
    cout << "Volume is not defined for circle." << endl;
}
```

I got red lines under `area()`, `perimeter()`, and `volume()` in my `Circle` class, which showed `"Error: inherited member is not allowed"`. I went through my class ppt and googled for answer but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you still have to declare the virtual methods in a derived class.

Comment: `Shape` doesn't look abstract. Its member functions should be pure virtual for that. In addition, it should declare a virtual destructor.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `virtual ~Shape() {}`

Comment: Just want to correct the terminology used in question. By abstract, you really mean a header file, and by concrete you really mean your definition file. Not sure if what you were really looking for is pure virtual methods.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You have to declare the over-ridden functions as part of your class definition

```
class Circle : public Shape
    {
    public:
        Circle(int);
        virtual void area(); // overrides Shape::area
        void perimeter();    // overrides Shape::perimeter
        virtual void volume();
    private:
        int r;
    };
```

Note that the use of `virtual` here is optional.

As n.m. noted, you should also include a virtual destructor in `Shape`.  You may also want to make its virtual functions pure virtual (based on your comment about `Shape` being abstract)

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    virtual void area() = 0;
    virtual void perimeter() = 0;
    virtual void volume() = 0;
};
```

Comment: @bames53 Is there a C++ `override` keyword?  I'm only aware of the [Microsoft extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/41w3sh1c.aspx) but you'd need to know that the code only needed to compile with recent versions of MSVC to use that.

Comment: wow this is really annoying, I almost can't see the point in bothering with base class inheritance if you have to do this.  It adds way more boilerplate code and makes messy headers. I'm trying to avoid having to repeatedly define the same function names for each of my inherited classes, but now I learn I have to do it all anyway. So much for cutting corners!

Comment: Concur with @KyranF. Tedious at best.

Comment: This declaration is very important to know directly just by looking at the class declaration (usually in an .h file) which methods have been reimplemented, and which ones have not been (and are thus using the default code from the base class).

Answer (score 9):

you have to declare the override methods too in the Circle class

```
class Circle : public Shape
    {
    public:
        Circle(int);
        virtual void area();
        virtual void perimeter();
        virtual void volume();
    private:
        int r;
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

First you should make you Shape class explicitly abstract:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void area() = 0;
    virtual void perimeter() = 0;
    virtual void volume() = 0;
};
```

This way you do not have to define that methods in class Shape, and what is more important if you forget to override any of abstract method in derived class and would try to create an instance of it, compiler will remind you.
Second when you override virtual method in derived class you need to declare them:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(int);

    virtual void area();
    virtual void perimeter();
    virtual void volume();
private:
    int r;
};
```