# Inherited member is not allowed, why?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

The basic issue boils down to this:

```
// header
class Calculator 
{
public:
    virtual int calculate(int a, int b);
};

class Adder : public Calculator 
{

};

// class file
int Adder::calculate(int a, int b) {return a + b;} // gives error
```

Why am I not allowed to do that?

I would've assumed that since `Adder` inherits `Calculator`'s members, I can just define their bodies as if they were its own, but apparently that isn't possible...

I've seen other answers in which they simply have to write the member definition again in the child class, but that to me seems like an awful lot of lines of code wasted repeating the same text over and over, so the question is...

Why can't I do it without overriding it in the child class's definition?

Also, please note that this isn't a question as to how to fix an error, it's a question about the mechanics of C++, and why something is or is not permitted to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is inherited member not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117591/why-is-inherited-member-not-allowed)

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare member functions outside the class definition.  Any methods you are going to define for a class (whether overriding or hiding with respect to a base class) must be declared in the class definition.

```
class Adder : public Calculator { };
```

Defines a class that derives from Calculator, but provides no additional functionality.  Also you probably meant to make the Calculator::calculate method virtual.  You are currently (edit: OP edited the question making calculate() virtual) hiding the base class method, rather than overriding it.  It makes a difference if you are going to deal with Calculator objects that may in fact be Adder objects at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it because you haven't explicitly said that Adder has a calculate method - and C++ is strict about it.  What would happen if you did then write Calculator::calculate in a separate source file?

Comment: then that would add the body to the main class, and not to the derived class... the derived class' members would still work as intended... ideally that is

Comment: Then you would be in the situation where compiling code in a separate source file changes the meaning of this file. Remember that you could have a calculate in both Calculate and Adder that do different things (not that it would be a good idea).

Comment: but the whole point is that they would do different things, I could add a Multiplier class that would also use the calculate method, but it shouldn't return a + b, it should return a * b instead

Comment: I meant completely different -- does some other unrelated calculation - which in your case would (or would not) be called depending on a completely different source file.