# cpp Socket, inheritage error

Tags: c++, sockets, inheritance

Im creating a socket class that has a static member for creating different types of sockets (client and server). Here is the interface:

```
    class Socket{
    public:
        int sendData(std::string _data);
        std::string receiveData();

        int closeSocket();

    protected:      
        Socket();
        virtual int initializeSocket() = 0;
        virtual int connectSocket() = 0;


    public:     // static members: Factory, etc.
        static Socket* createClientSocket(std::string _ip, std::string _port);
        static Socket* createServerSocket(std::string _port);

    protected:  
        WSADATA mWsaData;
        SOCKET mSocket;

        addrinfo *mResult, mHints;
```

The children are:

--> Server:

```
    class ServerSocket: public Socket{
    private:
        ServerSocket(const std::string _port);
        ~ServerSocket();

        int acceptClient();

    private:
        SOCKET mClientSocket;

        std::string mPort;
    };  //  class ServerSocket
```

--> Client:

```
    class ClientSocket: public Socket{
    private:
        ClientSocket(const std::string _ip, const std::string _port);
        ~ClientSocket();

    private:
        addrinfo *mPtr;

        std::string mServerIp, mServerPort;
    };  //  class ClientSocket
```

But while implementing initializeSocket and other members i get the error "inherited member is not allowed. As far as I concern, inherited classes can acces public and protected membes of the father class. Why this error arises?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
The error arises in many members, for example in the ServerSocket.cpp

```
int ServerSocket::initializeSocket(){  <<--- HERE in the name of the function appears 
    // Resolve the server address and port
    int iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, mPort.c_str(), &mHints, &mResult);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //..... ETC....

    freeaddrinfo(mResult);

    iResult = listen(mSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(mSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

Where i wrote "<<-- HERE..."

```
1>..\..\source\core\comm\ServerSocket.cpp(37): error C2509: 'initializeSocket' : member function not declared in 'BOViL::comm::ServerSocket'
1>          c:\programming\bovil\source\core\comm\ServerSocket.h(18) : see declaration of 'BOViL::comm::ServerSocket'
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the errors? And what are the *exact* errors? Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error log, as well as pointing out where in the source those errors are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is inherited member not allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117591/why-is-inherited-member-not-allowed)

Comment: I read that post Steve Howard, but I cant find the trouble :/

Comment: You can't just define member function like that without an actual declaration in the class. If you read the error message that should be pretty clear.

Comment: oh dammit... You've got the reason! I forgot to declare the member in the derived class... Thank you so much! it's solved :)

Answer (score 0):

The error was that derived class didnt declared the member functions in their declaration.

```
    class ClientSocket: public Socket{
    public:
        int sendData(std::string _data);  <<--- Add this

    private:
        ClientSocket(const std::string _ip, const std::string _port);
        ~ClientSocket();

        int initializeSocket(); <<--- Add this
        int connectSocket();  <<--- Add this

    private:
        addrinfo *mPtr;

        std::string mServerIp, mServerPort;
    };  //  class ClientSocket
```

and so on in the other class