# C++: Error with 'this' keyword

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create an poptart vending machine program within c++ and i am trying to use the this keyword, however i am always getting an error stating 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function. Below is a part of the code that i am getting one such issue in

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HasCredit.h"
using namespace std;


void insertMoney(int money)
{
    cout<<"You inserted: " << money;
    money = money+this->currentContext->getStateParam(Credit);
    this->currentContext->setStateParam(Credit,money);
    cout<< "Total: "<<money<<endl;
    this->currentContext->setState(Has_Credit);
}
```

Any suggestions onto why i am getting this error will be most appreciated. Cheers.

Edit: the insertMoney method is within a  class called HasCredit.

Edit2: member declarations are now made outside of the constructor

Edit3: Added state class declaration

The Class Definition Code is Below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "State.h"
#include "StateContext.h"
using namespace std;

class HasCredit: public State
{
    HasCredit (StateContext* Context) : State(Context) {
    }
        void insertMoney(int);
        void MakeSelectionCoating(int);
        void MakeSelectionFilling(int);
        void moneyRejected(void);
        void addPopTarts(int);
        void dispense(void);

};
```

The state class declaration code is shown Below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Transition.h"
using namespace std;

class State: public Transition
{
protected:
StateContext* currentContext;
public:
State(StateContext* Context);
};
```

Comment: this is a pointer to the object and is only available inside the non-static member functions of class ( which is the type of the mentioned object). Clearly insertMoney() does not belong to any class and hence the error. Read on this and its scope and meaning.

Comment: don't put `using namespase std;` in header files

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the State class?

Comment: yeah, i'll just make an edit now

Comment: How deep does this (inheritance) rabbit-hole go?

Comment: it goes quite deep as i've got other classes inheriting from state and they also have this pointers within them

Answer (score 4):

The `this` pointer is only valid inside a class. Your `insertMoney` function is not declared to be in a class. See http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/87-the-hidden-this-pointer/.

In your definiton of `insertMoney` (in the code, not the class), you do not declare it to be a member of `hasCredit`. You need to use `void hasCredit::insertMoney` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to attach `insertMoney` to a class. Try `ClassName::insertMoney` in your definition.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly why you're getting it.

The solution is to fix the definition of what you intend to be a member function, so that the compiler knows it is a member function.  Like this:

```
//   vv THIS WAS MISSING
void HasCredit::insertMoney(int money)
{
    ...
```

Your member declarations shown in the question are also in the wrong place.  They need to be inside the class body, but outside the constructor.  When overriding virtual member functions, you may want to show that to readers by using the `virtual` and `override` keywords.  (Note, `override` only works if you have a new, C++11 compiler.  For older compilers, use a comment `/* override */` instead)

```
class HasCredit: public State
{
    HasCredit (StateContext* Context) : State(Context) {  }
    // vv THIS....................CANNOT BE INSIDE HERE ^^
    virtual void insertMoney(int) override;
    ...
};
```

You probably want some of your members to be `public` as well.

Comment: The insertMoney function is inheriting from a class called State and i think thats where my issue lies

Comment: @user3158314, a FUNCTION cannot inherit a CLASS. You need to make a class that inherits State, and make insertMoney a member of that class.

Comment: @theunamedguy. I never said that the function inherits a class. I said it inherits from a class

Comment: @user3158314, do you mean that it is a member of a class?

Comment: @user3158314: theunamedguy is right.  The class `HasCredit` inherits from `State`.  The function `insertMoney` doesn't inherit anything, because only classes (and structs) can inherit.  It's a member of `HasCredit`, and overrides `State::insertMoney`

Comment: @user3158314, actually, you just need to declare insertMoney as a member of hasCredit with `void hasCredit::insertMoney(int money)`

Comment: i've just tried doing that and im getting an error stating inherited member is not allowed

Comment: i just tried doing void hasCredit::insertMoney(int money) and its stating that inherited member is not allowed

Comment: Well, try what's in my answer, not somebody else's comment.  That is add `HasCredit::` (capitalization counts) in the function definition, and don't add it in the declaration inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong:

class definition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "State.h"
#include "StateContext.h"
using namespace std;

class HasCredit: public State
{
    HasCredit (StateContext* Context) : State(Context) {
    }
    void insertMoney(int);
    void MakeSelectionCoating(int);
    void MakeSelectionFilling(int);
    void moneyRejected(void);
    void addPopTarts(int);
    void dispense(void);
};
```

Note that the methods should be declared **outside** of the constructor definition.

For the implemenation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HasCredit.h"
using namespace std;

void HasCredit::insertMoney(int money)
{
    cout<<"You inserted: " << money;
    money = money+this->currentContext->getStateParam(Credit);
    this->currentContext->setStateParam(Credit,money);
    cout<< "Total: "<<money<<endl;
    this->currentContext->setState(Has_Credit);
}
```

The method must be qualified with the name of the class... otherwise it would be considered a definition of a function... and a function does not have a *this*

Comment: i have tried doing this however i am getting an error stating inherited member is not allowed, even though i have done exactly as your code states above

Comment: the error is underlined on the insertMoney part of void HasCredit::insertMoney(int money)

Comment: @user3158314: You're still putting the member declarations inside the constructor, apparently, even though both jsantander and I told you that needed to be fixed, and showed how.

Comment: @BenVoigt... actually I'm puzzled why the compiler does not complain about having those declarations inside the constructor.  I can only guess they are taken as varibles of type function pointer...

Comment: @user3158314 check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117591/why-is-inherited-member-not-allowed might be of help

Comment: @jsantander: Not pointers.  They're forward declarations for functions.  If used, I'm pretty sure the compiler will search at namespace scope.  (Obviously the functions can't be *defined* inside the constructor, but declarations are allowed in local scope.  See the ["most vexing parse"](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/06/gotw-1-variable-initialization-or-is-it-310/).)